# How can I retrieve old data from Kafka to store in Mongodb

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How can i transfer old data from Kafka to MongoDB database, I had changed the topic of Kafka so because of that there was old data it did not come in MongoDB so how can I do it?

If I try to retrieve data from old topic then I get poll timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear how you define "old".

Kafka actively removes data from topics with retention policies. If data is deleted, you can never consume it.

While it is still retained, you simply set `auto.offset.reset=earliest` (in Connect, you add `consumer.` prefix to this and put in the worker properties file, not the connector itself), and start polling. Timeout errors are separate issue, and have nothing to do with retention time of the topic. By default, any consumer or connector will set this property to `latest` and not see *retained* data